# Script amoCrm в RailsApp

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, crm

Как преобразовать данный код, т к есть подозрения что рельсовое условие выполняется, но скрипт не срабатывает, при том что в наличии 2 скрипта, которые следует выполнить.

```
<%if current_po.slug == "moscow"%>
        <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myModal").click(function(){
                <script>var amo_forms_params =
                    {"id":11111,"hash":"q;lowjd9238huwef;ejfw","locale":"ru"};
                </script>
                <script id="amoforms_script" async="async" charset="utf-8" src=«https://
                forms.amocrm.ru/forms/assets/js/amoforms.js"></script>
            });
        });

        </script>
    <%end%>
```

Comment: Турболинки есть в проекте?

Comment: да, имеются.. )

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `$(document).ready(function()` на `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()`.

Comment: нет, кажется это не решение, т. к. тут ключевая загвоздка в том, что в рельсовом условии два скрипта, а не один.

Comment: "Кажется не решение" - вы заменили, но оба скрипта всё равно не грузятся? А при перезагрузке страницы они подгружаются?

Comment: все ок, спасибо. Решение оказалось абсолютно в другом месте, не там где ожидалось.